# How should Transient Resources be retrieved in a RESTful API

Tags: http, rest, resources, transient

For a while I was (wrongly) thinking that a RESTful API just exposed CRUD operation to persisted entities for a web application. When you code something up in "the real world" you soon find out that this is not enough. For example, a bank account transfer doesn't have to be a persisted entity. It could be a transient resource where you `POST` to `/transfers/` and in the payload you specify the details:

```
{"accountToCredit":1234, "accountToDebit":5678, "amount":10}
```

Using `POST` here makes sense because it changes the state on the server ($10 moves from one account to another every time this `POST` occurs).

What should happen in the case where it doesn't affect the server? The simple first answer would be to use `GET`. For example, you want to get a list of savings and checking accounts that have less than $100. You would then call something like `GET` to `/accounts/searchResults?minBalance=0&maxBalance=100`. What happens though if your search parameter need to use complex objects that wouldn't fit in the maximum length of a `GET` request.

My first thought was to use `POST`, but after thinking about it some more it should probably be a `PUT` since it isn't changing the state of the server, but from my (limited) understanding I always though of `PUT` as updating a resource and `POST` as creating a resource (like creating this search results). So which should be used in this case?

I found the following links which provide some information but it wasn't clear to me what should be used in the different cases:

[Transient REST Representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309058/transient-rest-representations/1309120#1309120)

[How to design RESTful search/filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering)

[RESTful URL design for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with your approach, it seems reasonable to me to use `GET` when searching for resources, and as said in one of your provided links, *the whole point of query strings is for doing things like search*. I also agree that `PUT` fits better when you want to update some resource in an idempotent way (no matter how many times you hit the request, the result will be the same).

So generally, I would do it as you propose. Now, if you are limited by the maximum length of `GET` request, then you could use `POST` or `PUT`, passing your parameters in a JSON, in a URI like:

```
PUT /api/search
```

You could see this as a "search resource" where you send new parameters. I know it seems like a workaround and you may be worried that REST is about avoiding verbs in the URIs. Well, there are few cases that it's still acceptable and RESTful to use verbs, e.g. in cases where calculation or conversion is involved to generate the result (for more about this, check [this](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/announcement_new_ebook_on_web_api_design/) reference).

PS. I think this workaround is still RESTful, but even if it wasn't, REST isn't an obsession and an ultimate goal. Being pragmatic and keeping a clean API design might be a better approach, even if in few cases you are not RESTful.